# Watching and compiling multiple sass directories with multiple config.rb files with gulp

Tags: sass, gulp, build-process, compass-sass

I've got a file tree roughly as follows:

```
sites
 |
 +-- all
 |    |
 |    +-- css/
 |    +-- scss/
 |    \-- config.rb
 |
 +-- mysite.com
 |    |
 |    +-- css/
 |    +-- scss/
 |    \-- config.rb
```

This is my gulpfile (simplified):

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    compass = require('gulp-compass');

gulp.task('compile-css', function() {
    return gulp
        .src("./sites/all/scss/*.scss")
        .pipe(compass({
            config_file: './sites/all/config.rb',
            sass: "./sites/all/scss"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("sites/all/css"));
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./sites/wirefly.com/**/*.scss', ['compile-css']);
});
```

Which currently works just fine for compiling all the scss files in the `/all/scss/` directory and dumping them into the `/all/css/` directory, as per the configuration in the `/all/config.rb` file.

Is there a way I can have gulp watch ALL scss files in the project and use the proper config.rb file for output? i.e files in `/all/scss/` would be compiled according to the `/all/config.rb` settings, while `/mysite.com/scss/` would be compiles according to the `/mysite.com/config.rb` settings.

Or maybe just get rid of the `config.rb` files entirely and leverage gulp to put the files where they should go?

I COULD write a separate task for the scss files in the `/mysite.com` directory but that's not elegant or scalable, should more subdirectories be introduced.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I ended up using a callback in the `"change"` event of the `watch` task, as such:

```
var relativePath;

gulp.task('main-compass', function() {
    return gulp
        .src(relativePath + '/*.scss')
        .pipe(compass({
            config_file: relativePath + "/../config.rb",
            sass: relativePath
        }));
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./sites/**/*.scss').on('change', function(file) {
        var regexDir = /sites(.*)/g;
        var partialDir = file.path.match(regexDir);
        relativePath = path.dirname(partialDir);

        gulp.run('main-compass');
    });
});
```

So the `relativePath` variable is assigned the relative path to the changed file, then the `main-compass` task utilizes the `config.rb` file that is one directory up from the changed sass file.

There may be a better way to do this, but this gets the job done for now.